# How to test my GAE site for performance

Tags: python, google-app-engine, load-testing

I am building a GAE site that uses AJAX/JSON for almost all its tasks including building the UI elements, all interactions and client-server requests. What is a good way to test it for highloads so that I could have some statistics about how much resources 1000 average users per some period of time would take. I think I can create some Python functions for this purpose. What can you advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to get Appstats hooked up and configured for your app -- it won't help you with the load-testing part itself, but gives you a ton of useful data about where your app is spending its time.

[Appstats for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html)

Answer (score 1):

Writing some python tests that can automate tests is a good way to measure performance.  If you want to measure the entire client experience consider trying the "Audit" tool in Google chrome.  The [chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) provide several resources for measuring performance.  To access the tools click the wrench in the top right corner then click tools, then developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a free linux micro instance from EC2 and then run ab (apache benchmark) with lots of requests.  You can change number of requests, concurrent requests and you can even launch multiple EC2 instances from different data centers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the budget for it, a professional load testing tool will save you a lot of time and produce more accurate results.  Some of those tools handle AJAX apps better than others. I will naturally recommend our product (Web Performance Load Tester) and one of our engineers will help you get it working with your site. You should, of course, evaluate other products to see what works best for your site. Load Impact and Browser Mob are online services that in many cases handle AJAX better than the more traditional tools (except ours!), but they also have downsides.